# Based on what should I determine where the state should live in a React structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While designing a Chat Messaging application, I have a panel which summarises the chats (the Left hand panel in Facebook messaging on browsers). It will show chats from the users and sort them based on the time (again, quite like facebook). In such an application should i assign the response containing the chat details to the containing parent component or the repetitive chat summary child components?

Comment: Best practice, you should be using the FLUX action-dispatcher-store-view pattern for this kind of thing. Store the messages (which are the result of an action call, say an API) in the store objects. Then retrieve them and update them in the view when required. This can be applied to a lot of different data paradigms.

https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html#content

Comment: The answer would vary depending on who you talk to. I would be in the "Put state elsewhere, Redux or something." camp. With that approach, I never would have asked this question. Store state externally, just have components grab them and render.

Comment: I would centralise the message storage - MobX and redux are useful for that. The message log is a verbatim reproduction of the store while the contacts is a computed property from the message store.